# In Python3, how to use a Gtk.Grid() layout container with a Webkit window

Tags: python, layout, webkit

I'm trying to pack a Webkit window + a close button in a grid layout container.  The code works using the box layout code (currently remarked out) but does not work using the grid layout code.

Sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
gi.require_version('WebKit2', '4.0')
from gi.repository import WebKit2


class  FileView:
    def __init__(self,file):
       window = Gtk.Window()
       window.connect("destroy", self.close_window, window)
       self.view = WebKit2.WebView()              
       self.view.load_uri(file)
       window.set_default_size(1100,900)

       cancelbtn=Gtk.Button(label="Close")
       cancelbtn.connect("clicked", self.close_window, window)

       ####box code here########
       #vbox = Gtk.VBox()
       #hbox = Gtk.HBox()
       #window.add(vbox)
       #vbox.add(self.view)
       #vbox.pack_end(hbox,False,False,0)
       #hbox.pack_end(cancelbtn,False,False,0)
       #########################

       ####grid code here#######
       grid = Gtk.Grid()
       window.add(grid)
       grid.add(self.view)
       grid.add(cancelbtn)
       #########################

       window.show_all()

    def close_window(self, event, window):
      #window.close()
      Gtk.main_quit()  #remark out to prevent closing entire app
      return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    FileView("https://duckduckgo.com")
    Gtk.main()
```

What am I missing to make the grid layout work instead of the box layout?